# How to add a second element with new id?

Tags: xml, xslt

This should be fairly easy but I am new to XSLT and I have a hard time finding the solution. I got the following XML:

```
<catalog>
    <book id="1">
        <author>Mike</author>
        <title>Tomas</title>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

and I am trying to add another `book` entry on top of it and change its `id` from `1` to `2`. I have tried the following which fails to change the attribute value though.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">2</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:element name="book">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="author">author1</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="title">title1</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">2</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <book id="1">
      <author>author1</author>
      <title>title1</title>
    </book>
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will need to add

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to make sure the catalog element or other elements and attributes are copied unchanged.

So all suggestions together result in the templates

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">2</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <book id="1">
      <author>author1</author>
      <title>title1</title>
    </book>
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

where we could then shorten the code to

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">2</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <book id="1">
      <author>author1</author>
      <title>title1</title>
    </book>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: sorry, you are right. I placed your code in the wrong place... Thank you!

Comment: just one question. Can you please explain the following:

`<xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>`

why do you use `copy-of` within the `copy` element?

Comment: The `xsl:copy` makes a shallow copy as you want to transform the attribute, so that allows us to use `apply-templates` to make sure the attribute template you have written is used to transform the attribute. The inner `xsl:copy-of` is used to copy the child elements you did not need to transform.

Comment: As I have done in the last snippet, if the identity transformation template is in place, we can shorten the code to call it and it does the same job, doing a shallow copy of the element and making sure attributes and child nodes are processed by matching templates, which is your template for the `id` attribute and then recursively the identity transformation for those nodes that don't need changes.

Comment: makes sense now. One last thing that came up just now. Since the addition of the book element is taking place before the attribute value is modified, how come not both element attributes match the template for the value to be transformed?

Comment: The normal processing takes the nodes from an input document and transforms that input document into a result document, a result element is not transformed further. You would need to store a result element in a variable and transform that explicitly (where in XSLT 1.0 you would first need to use `exsl:node-set($var)`).